# Move running EXE to new location without waiting for reboot

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to move the running EXE, but this gives `access denied because of running state`.  I could use `MoveFileEx(MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT)`, but that only acts after rebooting.

Is there any way to do this without waiting for the reboot?

```c
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    WCHAR szFilepath[MAX_PATH];
    std::wstring wFilepath;
    std::wstring wFilename;
    std::wstring wDestpath;

    /* Get the current executable's full path */
    wFilepath = std::wstring(szFilepath, GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, szFilepath, MAX_PATH));
    std::wcout << L"filepath: " << wFilepath << std::endl;

    /* Extract just the name */
    wFilename = wFilepath.substr(wFilepath.find_last_of(L"\\/") + 1);
    std::wcout << L"filename: " << wFilename << std::endl;

    /* Set the destination folder path and file name */
    wDestpath = L"D:\\" + wFilename;
    std::wcout << L"dest path: " << wDestpath << std::endl;

    // copys the file of your '.exe'

    if (!CopyFileW(wFilepath.c_str(), wDestpath.c_str(), FALSE)) {
        std::wcout << L"couldnt copy the file";
    }
    else {
        std::wcout << L"copied";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first step is to end the process that you want to delete. When it goes down you need to spawn some other application to do the actual delete.

Comment: in a level code how can this be done?

Comment: See here for some ideas http://www.catch22.net/tuts/win32/self-deleting-executables#

Comment: You need a helper application.  Your exe launches the helper, passing it any info it needs like your process ID and path(s), then your exe terminates itself.  The helper app waits for your process ID to end then does the copy and delete.  Search on something like "patching running executable" for existing answers.